# How spark loads the data into memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have total confusion in the spark execution process. I have referred may articles and tutorials, nobody is discussing in detailed. I might be wrongly understanding spark. Please correct me.

I have my file of 40GB distributed across 4 nodes (10GB each node) of the 10 node cluster.
When I say `spark.read.textFile("test.txt")` in my code, will it load data(40GB) from all the 4 nodes into driver program (master node)?
Or this RDD will be loaded in all the 4 nodes separately. In that case, each node RDD should hold 10GB of physical data, is it?
And the whole RDD holds 10GB data and perform tasks for each partition i.e 128MB in spark 2.0. And finally shuffles the output to the driver program (master node)

And I read somewhere "`numbers of cores in Cluster = no. of partitions`" does it mean, the spark will move the partitions of one node to all 10 nodes for processing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark doesn't have to read the whole file into memory at once.  That 40GB file is split into many 128MB (or whatever your partition size is) partitions.  Each of those partitions is a processing task.  Each core will only work on one task at a time, with a preference to work on tasks where the data partition is stored on the same node.  Only the 128MB partition that is being worked on needs to be read, the rest of the file is not read.  Once the task completes (and produces some output) then the 128MB for the next task cab be read in and the data read in for the first task can be freed from memory.  Because of this only the small amount of data being processed at a time needs to be loaded in to memory and not the entire file at once.

Also strictly speaking `spark.read.textFile("test.txt")` does nothing.  It reads no data and does no processing. It creates an RDD but an RDD doesn't contain any data.  And RDD is just an execution plan.  `spark.read.textFile("test.txt")` declared that the file test.txt will be read an used as a source of data if and when the RDD is evaluated but doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: Good explanation!!! Can you also explain where does the output from the current task is being stored before the next partition is being taken in for execution?

Comment: @PuneethReddyV It depends a bit on what kind of processing you are doing.  If the output of the task is the final output it will be written directly to the output file (or wherever your final output is going).  However if there are multiple stages in the processing job then the output of a task could be a shuffle.  In this case I'm not completely sure of the specifics but I believe spark uses some temporary files to store this data.

Comment: @PuneethReddyV As per my understanding, by default the intermediate output will be stored in RAM(MEMORY_ONLY). But this can be cofigured as DISK_ONLY, MEMORY_AND_DISK or MEMORY_ONLY.

Comment: @Learner That is for explicit caching of intermediate results (ie. explicitly calling `cache` or `persist` which is more a of a side effect and does affect processing.  A shuffle operation is caused by a join or repartition for example and works differently.

Comment: From the perspective of memory, does it mean spark will read single partition data into execution memory? The conclusion will help to determine the size of executor memory.